# IErrorInfo.GetDescription failed with E_FAIL(0x80004005)

Tags: excel, ssis

Getting this error while connecting to an excel data source

Code :

```
Con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Jet OLEDB:Registry 
       Path=""SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Jet\4.0"";Data Source=""" & FilePath & """;" 
       & "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;IMEX=1;HDR=NO""

Con.Open()
```

Error:

> at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionInternal..ctor(OleDbConnectionString
>   constr, OleDbConnection connection) at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
>   options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool,
>   DbConnection owningObject) at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup) at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection) at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.Open() at
>   ScriptTask_a70f59b01c864c5bb8e468d2a0030092.vbproj.ScriptMain.ReadExcelFile(String
>   FilePath, String FileExtension) in
>   C:\Users\sureshbs\AppData\Local\Temp\SSIS\cd482fe4061144a49e4880855a057950\ScriptMain.vb:line
>   316" {"IErrorInfo.GetDescription failed with E_FAIL(0x80004005)."}

Answer (score 2):

If you are doing this through VS2010, via Jet engine x64, then i had a the exact same error because my filepath was incorrect.

I have read about other people having the very same issue when using unsupported functions or user defined functions in their SQL syntax.